# Extract time against Max and Min values in r

Tags: r

For the table below, I would like to extract the time against the peak and trough of the values. The dataset is analogous to a groundwater level which is expected to peak coinciding a rainfall and gradually drop down until the next rainfall event. Here, I'd like to extract the records 1, 5 and 9 as Min Time (trough) and records 2 and 7 as Max time (peak). The peaks and troughs are defined as shown in the snapshot where in each of the colour is expected to be seen as an output.
In instances of same values on the 'CS', I'm hoping to do an average of lead of three records for peak while for the trough an average of lag of the previous three records

```
       structure(list(TIMESTAMP = c("25/06/2021 00:00", "25/06/2021 04:00", 
"25/06/2021 08:00", "25/06/2021 12:00", "25/06/2021 16:00", "25/06/2021 20:00", 
"26/06/2021 00:00", "27/06/2021 04:00", "27/06/2021 08:00"), 
    CS = c(70L, 138L, 120L, 100L, 80L, 110L, 150L, 100L, 60L)), row.names = c(NA, 
9L), class = "data.frame")
```

From a read of other posts, I started developing like the one below using lubridate and tidyr, however, I guess I'm lost and realising it's time for me to get some help. Any help highly appreciated.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
d <- mydata %>%
  gather("CS","Temp",-TIMESTAMP) %>%
  group_by(Date = date(TIMESTAMP), HoD = hour(TIMESTAMP)) %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = "Temp", .funs = list(Min = min, Max = max)) %>%
  filter(Temp == Min | Temp == Max) %>%
  arrange(CS, TIMESTAMP) %>%
  distinct(Temp, .keep_all = T) %>%
  mutate(MinMax = ifelse(Temp == Min, "MinTime", "MaxTime")) %>%
  spread("MinMax", "TIMESTAMP")
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 Min_Time  CS_Min  Max_Time  CS_Max 
1 25/06/2021 00:00  70  25/06/2021 04:00 138
2 25/06/2021 16:00  80  25/06/2021 04:00 138
3 25/06/2021 16:00  80  26/06/2021 00:00 150       
4 27/06/2021 08:00  60  NA NA
```

[image]

Comment: Please instead of that table try pasting the output of `dput(head(mydata))` so it's easier to replicate your code.

Comment: @SamuelCalderon - Thanks, edited to include the structure of the table.

Comment: @AravindanKalai "*Example, I'd like to extract records 1, 5 and 9 as Min Time (trough) and records 2 and 7 as Max time (peak).*" The sample data you give don't include records 7 and 9 (and the expected output doesn't match the sample input data). With only one record defining what you call is a "peak" it's hard to understand the logic behind the what constitutes a "trough" and what a "peak". Please include *representative* sample data and a clear problem statement.

Comment: @MauritsEvers - Thanks for spotting out. I've now included the rest of the records. Hopefully you might now able to see the trough (low values) and peak (high values). I guess I need a good sleep.

Comment: This is not clear to me. What makes an event a peak/trough? Why does record 2 get matched with record 7. These "events" occur at different days. Conversely, why does record 1 get matched with record 2 (same day)? How are peaks/troughs defined? What is the logic behind the mapping? Can you describe in words what you're trying to do?

Comment: @MauritsEvers - I've now added a snapshot to my original query to explain the peaks and troughs better. The expected output has been corrected for line 2, hope it all makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: How would you like to handle two consecutive peak/trough rows with the same value?

Comment: @AravindanKalai Can you explain **in words** what it is you're trying to do? I still don't understand how you match events with peaks/troughs. Sometimes they match in date. Sometimes they don't. Why? What are the rules? What about edge cases like Caspar mentions. The devil is in the detail...

Comment: @CasparV. - In instances of same values, I'm hoping to do an average of lead of three records for peak while for the trough an average of lag of the previous three records.

Comment: @AravindanKalai All these details are important and need to go into the main post. Comments are transient and may/will disappear. Please edit your post. Be verbose and explicit. This may appear clear as day to you but but please remember that we have no context on what you're working on.

Comment: @MauritsEvers - Basically I'm trying to get the inter event time periods of the peak and trough in the dataset. The dataset is analogous to groundwater level which is expected to peak coinciding a rainfall and gradually drop down until the next rainfall event. I'm essentially trying to extract the timings of these to work out the duration and the scale of difference in the subsequent process. I will add these details to my post as recommended. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not have to be hard to find single peaks and troughs, but a complicating factor is peaks and troughs that are more than one observation wide. Therefore I have added one such instance to your example data:

##### example input

```
df <- data.frame(CS = c(70L, 138L, 138L, 120L, 100L, 80L, 110L, 150L, 100L, 70L),
                 TIMESTAMP = c("25/06/2021 00:00", "25/06/2021 04:00", "25/06/2021 08:00", "25/06/2021 09:00", "25/06/2021 12:00",
                               "25/06/2021 16:00", "25/06/2021 20:00", "26/06/2021 00:00", "27/06/2021 04:00", "27/06/2021 08:00") )

> df
    CS        TIMESTAMP
1   70 25/06/2021 00:00
2  138 25/06/2021 04:00
3  138 25/06/2021 08:00
4  120 25/06/2021 09:00
5  100 25/06/2021 12:00
6   80 25/06/2021 16:00
7  110 25/06/2021 20:00
8  150 26/06/2021 00:00
9  100 27/06/2021 04:00
10  70 27/06/2021 08:00
```

##### step 1: identify clusters of consecutive row-ids that have the same CS

We will address the rows by their row id; i.e. the number in front of each row in the output of `df` above.

With `data.table::rleid()` we can quickly cluster the row ids of consecutive rows with the same CS-value. We then create a copy of `df` where we remove those 'duplicate' rows (`df_unique`):

```
library('data.table')
library('dplyr')
    
rleids <- rleid(df$CS)        # generate run-length type cluster ids

df_unique <- df %>%                       # create temporary df with only first of each cluster:
  mutate(org_rowid = row_number()) %>%    # save the original row number
  filter(CS != lag(CS) | is.na(lag(CS)))  # filter out rows that have identical CS as previous row
```

Results:

```
> rleids
 [1] 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

> df_unique
   CS        TIMESTAMP org_rowid
1  70 25/06/2021 00:00         1
2 138 25/06/2021 04:00         2
3 120 25/06/2021 09:00         4
4 100 25/06/2021 12:00         5
5  80 25/06/2021 16:00         6
6 110 25/06/2021 20:00         7
7 150 26/06/2021 00:00         8
8 100 27/06/2021 04:00         9
9  70 27/06/2021 08:00        10
```

##### step 2: identify (clusters of) rows higher / lower than the values around them

In the data frame with 'duplicate' values removed, we can easily find the peaks and troughs.

I've added `| is.na( ... )` to also include the first and last rows as either a peak or trough, even though we don't know what lies beyond them.

```
# find (row number of) peaks and troughs in df_unique
peaks <- df_unique %>%
  filter( (CS > lead(CS) | is.na(lead(CS))) & (CS > lag(CS) | is.na(lag(CS))) ) %>%
  pull(org_rowid)

troughs <- df_unique %>%
  filter( (CS < lead(CS) | is.na(lead(CS))) & (CS < lag(CS) | is.na(lag(CS))) ) %>%
  pull(org_rowid)
```

Results:

```
> peaks
[1] 2 8

> troughs
[1]  1  6 10
```

##### step 3: add row ids of 'duplicate' rows

As the final step, we will use the data in `rleids` to add row ids for all rows in each cluster. Since we can't preserve clusters in a vector, we will create two lists.

```
# add row numbers in the same cluster
peaks <- lapply(peaks, function(x) which(rleids == rleids[x]))
troughs <- lapply(troughs, function(x) which(rleids == rleids[x]))
```

Results:

```
> peaks
[[1]]
[1] 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 8

> troughs
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 6

[[3]]
[1] 10
```

##### optional step 4: cleanup

```
# cleanup
rm(df_unique, rleids)
```

##### complete code

```
library('dplyr')
library('data.table')

df <- data.frame(CS = c(70L, 138L, 138L, 120L, 100L, 80L, 110L, 150L, 100L, 70L),
                 TIMESTAMP = c("25/06/2021 00:00", "25/06/2021 04:00", "25/06/2021 08:00", "25/06/2021 09:00", "25/06/2021 12:00",
                               "25/06/2021 16:00", "25/06/2021 20:00", "26/06/2021 00:00", "27/06/2021 04:00", "27/06/2021 08:00") )

# step 1: identify clusters of consecutive row-ids thathave the same CS

rleids <- rleid(df$CS)        # generate run-length type cluster ids

df_unique <- df %>%                       # create temporary df with only first of each cluster:
  mutate(org_rowid = row_number()) %>%    # save the original row number
  filter(CS != lag(CS) | is.na(lag(CS)))  # filter out rows that have identical CS as previous row
  
# step 2: identify (clusters of) rows higher / lower than the values around them

peaks <- df_unique %>%
  filter( (CS > lead(CS) | is.na(lead(CS))) & (CS > lag(CS) | is.na(lag(CS))) ) %>%
  pull(org_rowid)

troughs <- df_unique %>%
  filter( (CS < lead(CS) | is.na(lead(CS))) & (CS < lag(CS) | is.na(lag(CS))) ) %>%
  pull(org_rowid)

# step 3: add row numbers in the same cluster

peaks <- lapply(peaks, function(x) which(rleids == rleids[x]))
troughs <- lapply(troughs, function(x) which(rleids == rleids[x]))

# step 4: cleanup

rm(df_unique, rleids)
```

Results:

```
> peaks
[[1]]
[1] 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 8

> troughs
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 6

[[3]]
[1] 10
```

Comment: Caspar - Thanks for your time and help on this. Much appreciated. I didn't knew of rleid, it's great to see how this was used. Cheers.